# display the current select of a form on the website

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form with lots of select fields.
I want to display the the choice of the current user on the page:

This is an example of a select field:

```
<select name="message[jungfrau-f4]">
    <option selected disabled">Stückzahl</option>
    <option value="jungfrau-f4: 5">5</option>
    <option value="jungfrau-f4: 10">10</option>
    <option value="jungfrau-f4: 10">10</option>
    // and so on
</select>
```

Now this is the js code which displays the current choice onto the page:

```
<script>
        var form = document.getElementById("form");
        var displayArea = document.getElementById("displayArea");

        var data = "";
        var headerAdded = false;
        form.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
        var select = event.target;
        if (select.tagName === "SELECT" && select.value !== "") {
            if (!headerAdded) {
            data += "<h2>Auswahl</h2><br>";
            headerAdded = true;
            }
            data += select.name + ": " + select.value + "<br>";
            displayArea.innerHTML = data;
        }
        });
</script>
```

This works nice and well:

[image]

But now there is the following problem:

If a user changes a select field which he/she already activated, It will add a new line with the new option instead of adjusting the already displayed. This is super confusing.

I'm already way out of my league here. Anybody a idea how to solve this?

I change the first select 3 times. now it generates three lines instead of updating the one line:

[image]

Comment: Let me clear. Do you want to show multiple select input's data? of just a single data whichever a user select?

Answer (score 0):

Because your 'var data = "";' is placed outside of the 'change' event, it keeps adding continuously. You should check if the current 'select' has already been added before.

Alternatively, if you don't have too many 'select' elements, you can retrieve and display all 'select' elements whose value is not 'Stückzahl' within the 'change' event.

```
<script>
    var form = document.getElementById("form");
    var displayArea = document.getElementById("displayArea");

    form.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
      var data = "<h2>Auswahl</h2><br>";
      var selectList = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
      for (var i = 0; i < selectList.length; i++) {
        var currentSelect = selectList[i];
        if (currentSelect.value !== "") {
          data += currentSelect.name + ": " + currentSelect.value + "<br>";
        }          
      }
      displayArea.innerHTML = data;
    });
</script>
```

**Update:**
put value in your first option

```
<option value="" selected="" disabled="">Stückzahl</option>
```

Comment: If I put the `var data` into the change event then the first line is always replaced with the last choice: https://codepen.io/Sepp/pen/RwYVqxp

Comment: @KSPR try this https://codepen.io/technogeek2015/pen/WNgOeOx

Comment: Thank you. But there is something interfereing and I don't kno what. I copied the entire form into the codepen. here all select fields is repopulated each time: https://codepen.io/Sepp/pen/RwYVqxp